# How can I render query data using map in a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started learning how to use React,  and I encountered the following problem: I need to render this data I fetched using graphql, when I console.log the data it shows up just fine. But when I try to map the array to get what I need it seems to be returning undefined.

How can I render the name and email of each subscriber using map?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const GET_SUBSCRIBERS_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    subscribers(stage: DRAFT) {
      name
      email
      id
    }
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIBERS_QUERY);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>@fsouza/table-data</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.subscribers.map((subscriber) => (
            <tr key={subscriber.id}>
              <td>{subscriber.name}</td>
              <td>{subscriber.email}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[console.log with the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnDPC.jpg)

[console.log after trying to map array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGc2F.jpg)

Comment: add `data?.subscribers.map(`, data is undefined on the first render

Comment: yep, I was missing that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is optional. And it is undefined while the query is loading.

```
 const { data, loading } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIBERS_QUERY);
```

You may consider adding a loading state, as follow:

```
if (loading) {
  return <p>Loading...</p> // Or whatever you want
}
```

Or just ad a check for subscribers to be present already (using a question mark):

```
data?.subscribers.map((subscriber) => ()
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is probably `undefined` before the actual fetch happens:

Change `data.` to `data?.`

```
const App = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIBERS_QUERY);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>@fsouza/table-data</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data?.subscribers.map((subscriber) => (
            <tr key={subscriber.id}>
              <td>{subscriber.name}</td>
              <td>{subscriber.email}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a simple question of when the data is available.
So before the data has been fetched, the data property is undefined. Thus the data object doesn't have a subscribers property, which is why it's failing.
When it fails you get an error, and it crashes.

If you wrap the map in a condition, you should work.

Putting data and a && in front does the trick. If `data` is defined (not a falsy value like undefined), execute the right-hand side.

```
{data && data.subscribers.map((subscriber) => (
    <tr key={subscriber.id}>
       <td>{subscriber.name}</td>
       <td>{subscriber.email}</td>
    </tr>
))}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation! It was just as you said